# addContentView and layoutInflater mix and blend the contents

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, layout-inflater

I have two separate xml files as shown below and both of them are placed inside the layout folder. One of the is named `firstlayout` and the other is `secondlayout`. In the activity, I want to show the contents of both using `layoutinflater`. Despite of, the `firstlayout.xml` its contents are oriented and aligned horizontally and the `secondlayout.xml` has a `relativelayout` aligned at the center, however, when I use `addcontentview` as shown below in my code, the output is a horizontal blended text of both placed at the top of the screen.

I expected the output on the screen to be, horizontal text at the top and horizontal text at the center. Please check my files and the code below and let me know what i am missing.

Java_Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.firstlayout);

    LayoutInflater loiViewInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    loiViewInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
    View mView = loiViewInflater.inflate(R.layout.secondlayout, null);
    addContentView(mView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

firstlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView00"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="first xml file00"
        android:gravity="top">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="first xml file01"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:gravity="top">
    </TextView>    
</LinearLayout>
```

secondlayout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
     <RelativeLayout 
          android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout00"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center">
               <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView00"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="second xml file00">
               </TextView>
               <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="second xml file01"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView00">
               </TextView>    
     </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to happen. The base layout is a FrameLayout so addContentView will just add everything on top of the existing layout.

Comment: OK, the first layout, solely displays two textviews horizontally at the top.And the second layout solely displays two textviews at the center. I want to merge/combine the contents of both using layoutinflater so that, I can get two textviews at the top and two textvies at the center in one screen. is it clear now?

Comment: Try replacing addContentView with addContentView(mView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

Comment: yes it worked thank you. Can you please explain how this changed the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the LayoutParams to WRAP_CONTENT for the second layout, so even though you set the gravity of the inner RelativeLayout to center, your outer LinearLayout is still going to align at the top left and size itself to wrap the content, so everything will end up in the top left.

Remove the LinearLayout from secondlayout.xml, you don't need it. Then change your code to:

```
View mView = loiViewInflater.inflate(R.layout.secondlayout, null);

FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

addContentView(mView, params);
```

Comment: thank you. but changing only the parameter in addcontentview to be matchParent, as @Broatian suggested, result in the required output

Comment: Sure, but then you are drawing a view which takes up the entire screen, even though you only have content in the middle. It also results in an additional view layer, which is a bad practice. Also, my answer explains why it was happening :)

Comment: why you used the variable params twice? Or it is just me I did not understand your code?!

Comment: I also commented out "LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);" and the result is the same

Comment: Oops, that's totally my bad. You only need the FrameLayout.LayoutParams. You need it to be a FrameLayout.LayoutParams so that you can set gravity, which ViewGroup.LayoutParams doesn't support.
Updated code above.