# How to shift layout position in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am fairly new to Android Programming and Java itself, so I have a beginner-ISH question that I hope someone can answer. I have a layout `activity_main.xml` and I am making a copy of the layout using this code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    getWindow().addContentView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.second, null),
                               new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                               ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                               ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Everything is all good in the hood. Works perfect, but when I do this it lays the layout right on top of the other layout, putting text on text, buttons on pictures, ext.

***How can I shift it down so I put the layout right below the other layout?***

Thank you so much!

Comment: You might want to check this question, since it's very similar to yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664432/addcontentview-and-layoutinflater-mix-and-blend-the-contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code instead:

```
        LayoutInflater loiViewInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View mView = loiViewInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0,400,0,0);

        addContentView(mView, params);
```

works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the layout to window which have frame layout and in frame layout views get stacked over each other. So you can do the following

1. Add you new layout to the existing one
2. If you are adding it to a frame layout add some margin/padding at top

Comment: Or don't add it to a FrameLayout, put it in a LinearLayout.